# Anyone can help me to solve this problem? "The archive “Xcode_10.3.xip” is damaged and can’t be expanded."

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, macos-catalina, macos-mojave

on mac version 10.14.6

When I tried to open file ".xip" that I had downloaded on Apple website "https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=xcode"

and then it was alert this message:
"The archive “Xcode_10.3.xip” is damaged and can’t be expanded."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by some network issue when downloading the file. Re-download the file typically fix this.

If the issue persist, try to download the file with a different network, or use proxy / VPN to avoid bad ISP caches.